# twig: IF with multiple conditions

Tags: php, twig, conditional-operator

It seem I have problem with a twig if statement.

```
{%if fields | length > 0 || trans_fields | length > 0 -%}
```

The error is:

```
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "|" ("name" expected) in
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work, it's like if twig was lost with all the pipes.

I've tried this :

```
{% set count1 = fields | length %}
{% set count2 = trans_fields | length %}
{%if count1 > 0 || count2 > 0 -%}
```

but the if also fail.

Then tried this:

```
{% set count1 = fields | length > 0 %}
{% set count2 = trans_fields | length > 0 %}
{%if count1 || count2 -%}
```

And it still doesn't work, same error every time ...

So... that lead me to a really simple question: does Twig support multiple conditions IF ?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

If I recall correctly Twig doesn't support `||` and `&&` operators, but requires `or` and `and` to be used respectively. I'd also use parentheses to denote the two statements more clearly although this isn't technically a requirement.

```
{%if ( fields | length > 0 ) or ( trans_fields | length > 0 ) %}
```

Expressions

```
Expressions can be used in {% blocks %} and ${ expressions }.

Operator    Description
==          Does the left expression equal the right expression?
+           Convert both arguments into a number and add them.
-           Convert both arguments into a number and substract them.
*           Convert both arguments into a number and multiply them.
/           Convert both arguments into a number and divide them.
%           Convert both arguments into a number and calculate the rest of the integer division.
~           Convert both arguments into a string and concatenate them.
or          True if the left or the right expression is true.
and         True if the left and the right expression is true.
not         Negate the expression.
```

For more complex operations, it may be best to wrap individual expressions in parentheses to avoid confusion:

```
{% if (foo and bar) or (fizz and (foo + bar == 3)) %}
```

Comment: And of course I had no chance of finding that wonderful and time-saving table when looking at the IF documentation : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html  Thanks for the solution !

Comment: They tend to use the wiki on github to more thoroughly document their code. That table comes from [here](https://github.com/vito/chyrp/wiki/Twig-Reference)

Comment: Using != didn't seem to work for me (may be a bug?): {% if (key != 'string1') or (key != 'string2') or (key != 'string3') %} so I had to use (key == 'stringN') for all of them and put what I needed in the 'else' statement

Comment: You need to use the `not` operator to negate the expression.

Comment: I was confused by the author's definition of '%'. As in PHP, '%' is for mod (modulus division)/calculating the remainder. If you want integer division, use '//'

Comment: you forgot the ternary operator `?`

Comment: It may be noteworthy - twig allows only lowercase `and` and `or`, so `AND` and `OR` won't work. Since it shows up error that googling out brings here, I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Twig 2 documentation on if condition: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html

Answer (score 3):

Using `!=` for multiple conditions does not work for me either, however `==` does work - indeed this seems like a bug.

Possible work around.

```
{% if key not in ['string1', 'string2'] %}
// print something
{% endif %}
```