# Not clause for Twig templates

Tags: php, twig

How do I do a NOT clause in a Twig template similar to PHP's `!`?  Given `sick` values of either `true` or `false`, I tried the following, but it throws an error.

```
{% if !sick %}
    Kenny is NOT sick.
{% elseif dead %}
    You killed Kenny! You bastard!!!
{% else %}
    Kenny looks okay --- so far
{% endif %}
```

Comment: "if not var"? Out on the run so couldnt check atm, strange if its not mentioned in the docs

Comment: @JimL  I was looking in the IF section http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html.  Turned out to be located elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `not` keyword as negation.

```
{% if not sick %}
    Kenny is NOT sick.
{% elseif dead %}
    You killed Kenny! You bastard!!!
{% else %}
    Kenny looks okay --- so far
{% endif %}
```

Following this [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#expressions) page and this [answear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8388696/4031969).