# TWIG syntax do not show field IF

Tags: php, mysql, twig

I have the script written in TWIG.

```
Weight: {{ doc.weight }} kgs<br />
```

// This part of script shows text information from "detail" and "info" MySQL fields ONLY IF these fields is NOT empty

```
                {% if "" == doc.info_hl %}
                    {% if '' != doc.detail_code %}
                        <b>Info: {{ doc.info }}</b>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    Info: {{ doc.info_hl|raw }}
                {% endif %}
                <br />

                {% if "" == doc.detail_code_hl %}
                    {% if '' != doc.detail_code %}
                        <b>Details: {{ doc.detail_code }}</b>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <b>Details: {{ doc.detail_code_hl|raw }}</b>
                {% endif %}
```

Sometimes MySQL field "weight" have values "0.00"

How to modify the code above - DO NOT SHOW "weight" MySQL field IF value in this field "0.00" ?
We can see above how we can do it with empty text fields, but how to do that with decimal fields equals to "0.00" ?

Thanks in advance for any hint to try !

Comment: I do not see `weight` in your code.  Please provide the relevant block of code to provide more context, as well as show a good faith effort to resolve your issue.

Comment: Weight: {{ doc.weight }} kgs<br /> - in the beggining of the code above !

Comment: @Ninir do you mean `{% if "0.00" == doc.weight %}
 {% if '' != doc.weight %}
Weight: {{ doc.weight }} kgs`

Comment: I mean `{% if '0.00' == doc.weight %} Weight: {{ doc.weight }} kgs {% endif %}`.
According to the value you want to check, the above will fit your needs. However, Mike is right saying that if you want to check that doc.weight is not empty and not 0, then checking `{% if doc.weight is not empty %}Weight: {{ doc.weight }} kgs {% endif %}` would be even better

Comment: @Ninir it works `{% if '0.00' == doc.weight %} Weight: {{ doc.weight }} kgs {% endif %}` but vise versa - it shows all where weight '0.00' and DO NOT show all other. It's very near a solution I'm looking for - but I need something `{% if NOT '0.00' == doc.weight %}` ...but I can't find such TWIG syntax "if NOT"..

Comment: @Ninir YES - it finally works, you're right, I tried `if not` but forgot to add round brackets `('0.00' == doc.weight)`. So the final code is `{% if not ('0.00' == doc.weight) %} Weight: {{ doc.weight }} {% endif %}` - it hides all lines where weight = 0.00 and shows all others !

Comment: @Serge Made an official answer, so you can select the appropriate answer to it :)

Comment: @Ninir Done :) have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

What about simply write

```
{% if '0.00' != doc.weight %} Weight: {{ doc.weight }} kgs {% endif %}
```

or even better

```
{% if not ('0.00' == doc.weight) %}... {% endif %}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the `is empty` test in the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/empty.html).  This test operates the same as the PHP `empty()` function.  Here is a handy Type [Comparison Table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to help you get any idea of what it will return.

If it is expected that this field will only ever contain numbers, or `String` representations of numbers, you can get around `empty('0.00') === FALSE` by adding a `0` to the variable:

```
empty('0.00' + 0) === TRUE
// In Twig: {%if ($value + 0) is empty %}
```

Here is a list of [available Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8388696/1301994) available in Twig Conditionals.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right direction because field 0.00 is not empty