# How can I check multiple if conditions in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, octobercms, craftcms

How can I check multiple if conditions in twig?
Neither of these seem to work
Also they all seem a but messy and heavy.

```
  {% if pageClass != "page-home" %}
  {% if bodyClass != "500" %}
  {% if bodyClass != "404" %}
         {% include '_components/type-bg' with {
                    content: {
                        slug: entry.slug|split(' ')|slice(0, 1)|join
                    },
                } only %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
```

I have also tried the below

```
    {% if (pageClass != "page-home") or (if bodyClass != "500") or (if bodyClass != "404")%}

      {% include '_components/type-bg' with {
                    content: {
                        slug: entry.slug|split(' ')|slice(0, 1)|join
                    },
                } only %}

    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twig: IF with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388537/twig-if-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: @LeKhan9 Nope. My examples above show that I've tried that solution and it doesn't work

Comment: @Jessica Shouldn't it be `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: @Iwan-Wijaya I want check if ANY of these conditions are true. If any of them are true then include this template with the content.
A page can't be 500 404 and page-home :-/

Comment: Oh I didn't read the values, I assumed the logic in your first code was correct.. I think it should be `{% if pageClass != "page-home" or bodyClass != "500" or bodyClass != "404 %}` ?

Comment: @DarkBee - my saviour! How does this work? Because the pages with bodyClass of 500 and 404 are including the template 'type-bg' - could you explain like i'm 5 so I understand and can fix it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `and` as your `all condition need to satisfy` to `execute that code` so it must be `and`

```
{% if pageClass != "page-home" and bodyClass != "500" and bodyClass != "404" %} 
     {% include '_components/type-bg' with {
         content: {
             slug: entry.slug|split(' ')|slice(0, 1)|join
         },
     } only %}   
{% endif %}
```

> **Better solution** would be from `code block` just use PHP code [you can do all PHP stuff here] to achieve this using `switch case or etc ..` and pass only **flag** like `needToInclude` as **boolean** to view and just use that.

[image]

```
{% if needToInclude %} 
     {% include '_components/type-bg' with {
         content: {
             slug: entry.slug|split(' ')|slice(0, 1)|join
         },
     } only %}   
{% endif %}
```

if any doubt please comment

Comment: Still need more coffee I guess - anyway +1 for doing it on the `PHP` side anyway. I'd personally would add a custom function to `twig` if I need this check more than once though

Comment: yah, but seems according to user/her experience i guess `code block php code` can help her, adding custom function will be overwhelming for user :) , but yes i agree for multiple uses `function` makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

The correct check would be the following

```
{% if pageClass != 'page-home' and bodyClass not in [ 500, 404, ] %}
```

Meaning execute when the `pageClass` is not the home page and make sure the bodyClass is not an erroneous state